# How to check Server's(zimbra) open pop3 which is not porvided?

Tags: email, port, pop3, webmail, zimbra

I am student of DA-IICT, Here we have **Zimbra mail Server**

They haven't provided **POP3 port** to us, there is one port for pop3 is open that all of my professor uses.

I have checked Zimbra's *setting* it's not there.

My college's webmail link [here](http://webmail.daiict.ac.in/).